# linking tag with onMouseUp triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I need an `<a>` element (or whatever) to work (go to the specified link) only on the MouseUp event not by clicking.

so how is this possible ?

Comment: Why would you break functionality everyone's used to?

Comment: Maybe I'm designing a special user interface

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" onmouseover="this.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething(elem) {
        elem.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
    }
</script>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" onmouseover="doSomething(this)">test</a>
```

Comment: these codes do nothing but changing the href attribute. I want it to OPEN the url defined in the href attr.
but thank for your time.